# Is it possible to implement delayed validation for an control in react-form-hook?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-forms

I have a custom validation for an Input field,
mode: "onChange"
Custom validation is to check if the user input text is present in an array of string,
Suppose my array size increases, performancce will be hit (since validation triggers for onChange)

So, my question is , if it is possible to trigger this custom validation, 3 seconds from the moment user stops typing.
or any other create solution would be helpful,

FYI: I have other validation along with the custom validation.
Using : MUI
Library: react-form-hook

Thank You

I am currently using mode:"onBlur" as a workaround.

Comment: Of course, it's possible. If you are using `onBlur` mode, then the validation will only trigger when the input field loses focus. This might be a good workaround if you don't want to validate on every change, but it might not be ideal if you want to give the user immediate feedback. Therefore, I'd suggest `onChange` mode with debounce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using lodash:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash'; // Import Lodash library (or use your own debounce implementation)

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  // Your custom validation function
  const customValidation = (value) => {
    const arrayOfStrings = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']; // Your array of strings
    return arrayOfStrings.includes(value);
  };

  // Debounced validation function
  const debouncedValidation = _.debounce((value) => {
    // Perform your custom validation here
    const isValid = customValidation(value);
    // Handle the validation result (e.g., update form state, show errors, etc.)
    console.log(`Validation result: ${isValid}`);
  }, 3000); // Wait for 3 seconds before triggering the validation

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setInputValue(value);
    // Trigger the debounced validation function with the latest value
    debouncedValidation(value);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      // Add other props needed for your Input component from MUI library
    />
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this --

```
 const { onChange, ...rest } = register()
    
 debounce(onChange())
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, solved this with awesome-debounce-promise package - https://github.com/slorber/awesome-debounce-promise

```
validate: debouncePromise(async (value) => {
  return await validatePhoneNumber(value) || 'Phone number is invalid';
}, 500),
```